# ready 0/1 in bitnami/mongo

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, bitnami

I am getting a 0/1 ready state when i run `kubectl get pod -n mongodb`

To install binami/mongo I ran:

```
    helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
kubectl create namespace mongodb
helm install mongodb -n mongodb bitnami/mongodb --values ./factory/yaml/mongodb/values.yaml
```

when I run `kubectl get pod -n mongodb`

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
mongodb-79bf77f485-8bdm6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   69 (55s ago)   4h17m
```

Here I want the ready state to be 1/1 and status running

thenI ran kubectl describe pod -n mongodb to view the log, and I got

```
    Name:         mongodb-79bf77f485-8bdm6
Namespace:    mongodb
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-58-58.ec2.internal/192.168.58.58
Start Time:   Tue, 19 Jul 2022 07:31:32 +0000
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
              helm.sh/chart=mongodb-12.1.26
              pod-template-hash=79bf77f485
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.47.246
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.47.246
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongodb-79bf77f485
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:   docker://11999c2e13e382ceb0a8ba2ea8255ed3d4dc07ca18659ee5a1fe1a8d071b10c0
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.2-debian-10-r0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bitnami/mongodb@sha256:add0ef947bc26d25b12ee1b01a914081e08b5e9242d2f9e34e2881b5583ce102
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 19 Jul 2022 11:46:12 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 19 Jul 2022 11:47:32 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  69
    Liveness:       exec [/bitnami/scripts/ping-mongodb.sh] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [/bitnami/scripts/readiness-probe.sh] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                    false
      MONGODB_ROOT_USER:                root
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mongodb'>  Optional: false
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:             no
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_DISABLE_JAVASCRIPT:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL:           yes
      MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER:              27017
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from datadir (rw)
      /bitnami/scripts from common-scripts (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-nsr69 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  common-scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      mongodb-common-scripts
    Optional:  false
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mongodb
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-nsr69:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                     ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  30m (x530 over 4h19m)    kubelet  Readiness probe failed: /bitnami/scripts/readiness-probe.sh: line 9: mongosh: command not found
  Warning  BackOff    9m59s (x760 over 4h10m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m6s (x415 over 4h19m)   kubelet  Liveness probe failed: /bitnami/scripts/ping-mongodb.sh: line 2: mongosh: command not found.
```

Don't understand the log or where the problem is coming from

How can I make the ready state 1/1 and a running status

Comment: Your readiness and liveliness probes are failing due to this error `mongosh: command not found`.   If you search the that error on search engines, you will get some more insight about the error.

Comment: I am using cloud9 as my ide, how will I add the mongosh command

Comment: @P.... I think `mongosh` should come with the Chart! I'm experiencing the same error and didn't find a solution yet.